# Is there a way to create a verification system?

Tags: file, verification, forum, xenforo

I am using XenForo, and was wondering, is there a way to create a verification system.
What do I mean by that is, when a user creates a post and uploads a file, it would show near name or the file - unverified. 
An admin should check it, and if it's clean - set it to verified.

Any kind of help would be really helpful. Hope are having a good day!

Comment: I believe this is already a feature of Xenforo called "post moderation".

Answer (score 0):

There is no "attachment moderation" feature in Xenforo.  vBulletin has this feature but Xenforo does not.  There is only a "post moderation" feature, which would require you to approve all posts regardless of content.

If you buy the [Resource Manager](https://xenforo.com/xf2-docs/manual/resource-manager/) official addon you can turn off regular attachments and force the user to use the Resource Manager when uploading files.  Then set Resource Manager to require approval for all resources.  This is the best solution as people can continue to post without approval but only when they upload files will it require approval.